# Is there an easy way to use BlueprintJS Icons in React Native?

Tags: react-native, blueprint, blueprintjs

I want to use these icons:

https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#icons

In my react native project. Wondering if there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that icons as CSS are legacy as of Blueprint 2.0. You can do it, but I'm not sure how it will work.

You can read more about it here [here](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/icon.css).